# Flex - Search/Filter DataGrid by Text Input

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, filtering, textinput

I’m using a filter setup that I found online and I’m having trouble filtering my mx:DataGrid using three components – comboBox, checkbox and text input. The checkbox and comboBox are working properly with my IFilter interface and Filter class, but I’m unable to get the search input working correctly. Here’s of the code from the source files

---

```js
package com.daveoncode.filters {
 
//Defines a common interface that must be implemented by all the filters.
 
 public interface IFilter {
  
  function apply(item:Object):Boolean;
  
 }
 
}

package com.daveoncode.filters {
 
 // The only purpose of Filter is to be wrapped by one or more filters (classes which extend AbstractFilter)
 
 public class Filter implements IFilter {

  // A wildcard which means "all values are accepted"
  
  public static const ALL_VALUES:String = "*";
  
  public function Filter() {
   
  }

  // This is a basic implementation of IFilter interface, the value returned is always true and only apply() 
  // methods implemented by subclasses of AbstractFilter have real buisiness logic implementation
   
  //@return Boolean <p>Always true</p>
   
  public function apply(item:Object):Boolean {
   
   return true;
   
  }
  
 }
 
}

package com.daveoncode.filters {
 
 public class SearchFilter extends AbstractFilterDecorator {
  
  // @param target IFilter <p>A reference to a wrapped IFilter object</p>
  // @param value Object <p>Value against which the filter is applied</p>
  
  public function SearchFilter(target:IFilter, value:Object) {
   
   super(target, value);
   
  }
  
// Impl of IFilter int by overr the dummy apply() of AbstractFilterDecorator
  
  override public function apply(item:Object):Boolean {
   

 return this._target.apply(item) && (this._value == item.Package || this._value == Filter.ALL_VALUES);
   
  }
  
 }
 
}
```

---

I’m trying to get the search functionality to work with my applyFilterRefresh() filter function below. Currently it does search the DataGrid, but it only filters case sensitive exact matches. I’m looking for it to filter after each stroke.

---

```js
private function applyFiltersRefresh():void {
       
  var data:ArrayCollection = ArrayCollection(sourceData);
  var filter:IFilter = new Filter();
     
  //combo box filtering - works great!
  filter = new FacilityTypeFilter(filter, facilityFilter.value);
  filter = new BedRangeFilter(filter, bedFilter.value);
    
  //checkbox filtering – works great!
  if (hideHealthcareVar == "Healthcare"){
  filter = new HideHealthcareFilter(filter, hideHealthcareVar.valueOf());
    }
    
  //Search box filtering – needs 
   if (search.text.length > 0){
   var tempSearch:String = search.text;
    filter = new HideHealthcareFilter(filter, tempSearch);
  }
    
  data.filterFunction = filter.apply;
  data.refresh();
   
 
    
 }
```

---

I am able to filter my datagrid (by each key stroke and non-case sensitive) this way, but because then the filters end up overriding each other instead of doing both at the same time. That’s why I’m trying to include it in my ApplyFiltersRefresh() functions. Sorry for the lengthy post and thanks in advance for the help!!

---

```js
private function budgetGrid_filterFunc(item:Object):Boolean {
  if (search.text.length == 0) return true;
  var f:String = "ig";
  var packageSearch:RegExp = new RegExp(search.text, f);
  var packageMatch:Boolean = packageSearch.test(item.Package);
    
  var itemSearch:RegExp = new RegExp(search.text, f);
  var itemMatch:Boolean = itemSearch.test(item.ItemNum);
    
  var descriptionSearch:RegExp = new RegExp(search.text, f);
  var descriptionMatch:Boolean = descriptionSearch.test(item.ItemDescription);
    
  return (packageMatch || itemMatch || descriptionMatch);
    
    
}

private function searchInput_change():void {
    

  if (search.text.length == 0) {
   budgetGrid.dataProvider.filterFunction = null;
  } else {
   budgetGrid.dataProvider.filterFunction = budgetGrid_filterFunc;
  }
   budgetGrid.dataProvider.refresh();
    
    
  }
```

Comment: The method `applyFiltersRefresh` seems OK to me. Why are you changing the filter function again in `searchInput_change`. If the `text.length` is zero then in that case you don't need to set filter function to null. Actually you don't even need this function, IMO.
Why have you written one more function `budgetGrid_filterFunc` for filtering?

Comment: What problem are you facing with search input? Every time it changes the changed text should get passed in `HideHealthcareFilter` and it should be working fine.

Comment: The applyFlterRefresh is applied first, by the comboBoxes which narrows my datagrid down to about 445 search results (There are about 4500 items in my XML file). I think because the two filters are separate, the searchInput_Change starts to filter the 4500 instead of the 445 showing. So once you clear the text input, the datagrid would then show all 4500. I was able to get it working by combining the searchINput_change functionality with my searchFilter class.

Answer (score 0):

```js
package com.daveoncode.filters {
 
 /**
  * @author Davide Zanotti (davidezanotti@gmail.com)
  */
 public class searchFilter extends AbstractFilterDecorator {
  
  /**
   * @param target IFilter <p>A reference to a wrapped IFilter object</p>
   * @param value Object <p>Value against which the filter is applied</p>
   */
  public function searchFilter(target:IFilter, value:Object) {
   
   super(target, value);
   
  }
  
  /**
   * Implementation of IFilter interface by overriding the dummy apply() of AbstractFilterDecorator
   */
  override public function apply(item:Object):Boolean {
   var f:String = "ig";
   var packageSearch:RegExp = new RegExp(this._value, f);
   var packageMatch:Boolean = packageSearch.test(item.Package);
   
   var itemSearch:RegExp = new RegExp(this._value, f);
   var itemMatch:Boolean = packageSearch.test(item.ItemNum);


   return this._target.apply(item) && (packageMatch  || itemMatch);
   
  }
  
 }
 
}
```